# Return ID on INSERT to MsAccess Db?

Tags: .net, ms-access, ado.net

I want get the id of the new added record. Is there a way to get it through **ADO.NET**???

id is the **PK**, and it's data type is **AutoNumber**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SELECT @@IDENTITY` after insert statement has fired.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0(v=VS.80).aspx

See the section labeled "Retrieving Microsoft Access Autonumber Values"

sort version

```
OleDbCommand cmdNewID = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY",
            connection)
```